# SublimeText 3 in vintage mode expanding folded code

Tags: sublimetext3

When going down (<kbd>j</kbd>) multiple times (from current cursor position at `minOccurs` expands the folded element. It's really annoying, because it only happens from time to time, when caret is exactly above the yellow ellipsis.

Any way how to prevent this behavior?

[image: Demo of cursor position]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May want to check out https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Vintageous. It's a more feature complete version of vim mode for ST. I also just tried reproducing your issue with the plugin and it seemed okay. Though it was quick, so I may have missed something.

Comment: Well. It worked. For some random reason it also changed my `caret_style` to `smooth` instead of `solid`, but i've already fixed that. Thanks.